# this version is not compatible in Samsung Galaxy Star GT-S5282

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

I have developed one android application, its available in Google Play Store for all the devices post 2.2. But, while trying to download the application from Samsung Galaxy Star GT-S5282, which is having 4.1.2. we are getting this error **this version is not compatible for this phone**

manifest code:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Below Permission used:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Please advice me on this Issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helping you [Google Support Devices](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) and I found another one who asked a similar question: [Android Device not supported by app why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976216/android-device-not-supported-by-app-why)

Comment: Maybe this helps better: In [Google play store say my android app is incompatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de) that there are this solution maybe fits: `The feature declaration can include an android:required=["true" | "false"] attribute (if you are compiling against API level 5 or higher), which lets you specify whether the application (...)`